# Attempt to index local pID: a number value

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

How to make a script constantly check for a value change and if the value changes toggle a GUI on or off. My code does not give me any errors it just simply does nothing when the value changes.

```
pID=script.Parent.prgrmID.Value
icnID=script.Parent.prgrmID.icnID.Value
if(pID==0 and icnID==0)then
    script.Parent.Visible=false
elseif(pID>0 and icnID>0)then
    script.Parent.Visible=true
elseif(pID>0 and icnID==0)then
print("ICON NOT FOUND")
script.Parent.prgrmIcon.Image="http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=413746335"
end


script.Parent.prgrmID.Changed:connect(function()
if(pID==0 and icnID==0)then
    script.Parent.Visible=false
elseif(pID>0 and icnID>0)then
    script.Parent.Visible=true
elseif(pID>0 and icnID==0)then
print("ICON NOT FOUND")
script.Parent.prgrmIcon.Image="http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id=413746335"
end
    end)
```

It does not give an error or anything

Comment: Your code doesn't include the line where this error happens. You need to show the full code and the line number shown in the error.

Comment: I said I did not get an error. It just did not do anything. There is no specific line.

Comment: Then the title of your submission doesn't make sense as `Attempt to index local pID: a number value` *is* the actual error message you'd see when indexing a number value.

Comment: You can avoid duplicating your code by using a single function for both the event connection and initial call.

Comment: Also, pID (and icnID) will never change since it's a variable being assigned a number. Change pID to `script.Parent.prgrmID`, then reference the value with `pID.Value`

Comment: [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/75fdf290da1eb7ce497573cfe5953ee3)

Comment: Both of our code have the exact same problem. I have a button to make the value change but it still won't change the image or execute.

Comment: I narrowed the problem down to the IF command is not executing and I do not know why.